# Mudar dado dentro de atributo data

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma página, onde possui um timer.
Ou seja, quando a página é aberta, após 40 segundos, uma *section* do site é carregada. Isso acontece devido a um serviço de terceiros, não consigo manipular esse tipo de informação.

Mas gostaria de manipular isso no meu navegador.

Por exemplo, ao carregar a página, o atributo recebe o valor 800.

```
data-delay-duration="800"
```

Eu gostaria de mudar isso. Não consigo fazer isso diretamente no site, pois como comentei, isso é um serviço de terceiro.

Eu instalei o *Tampermonkey* para Google Chrome, acho que pode haver essa possibilidade. Mas, gostaria de saber como fazer isso.
Seria algo com o *attr* do JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o navegador não tiver suporte ao `.dataset` então pode usar `.setAttribute` para trocar o valor e `.getAttribute` para obter ele, assim:

```js
var teste = document.getElementById('teste');
teste.setAttribute("data-delay-duration", "100");

console.log("data-delay-duration:", teste.getAttribute("data-delay-duration"));
console.log("source:", document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span id="teste" data-delay-duration="800"></span>
```

Só pra constar, apesar do caniuse afirmar que IE8, 9 e 10 tem suporte parcial ao `dataset` e `data-` em https://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset, na verdade eles se referem ao uso de `getAttribute` mesmo, ou seja `.dataset` não esta disponível, conforme a mensagem deles:

> Partial support refers to being able to use data-* attributes and access them using getAttribute.

Então se necessitar de um destes navegadores terá que usar o`.setAttribute`.

Se for para aplicar para multiplos elementos, como um `NodeList`, pode usar qualquer método para isto (dependendo dos elementos), como alguns exemplos:

- `document.getElementsByTagName`
- `document.getElementsByName`
- `document.querySelectorAll`

Creio que o `querySelectorAll` é o mais simples de usar, assim:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.foo, .baz');

for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; ++i) {
    els[i].setAttribute("data-delay-duration", "100");
}

console.log("source:", document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="foo" data-delay-duration="800"></span>
<span class="bar" data-delay-duration="800"></span>
<span class="baz" data-delay-duration="800"></span>
<span class="foo" data-delay-duration="800"></span>
<span class="foo" data-delay-duration="800"></span>
<span class="foo" data-delay-duration="800"></span>
```

Veja que nesse exemplo somente elementos com `class=foo` e `class=baz` tem o valor trocado

**Nota:** para checar se o DOM já carregou você pode executar o script assim:

```
(function () { //Isola o escopo para evitar conflito com outras funções e vars

    function trigger() {
        var els = document.querySelectorAll('.foo, .baz');

        for (var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; ++i) {
            els[i].setAttribute("data-delay-duration", "100");
        }
    }

    if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
        trigger();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", trigger);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Verdade Guilherme, tem que ter suporte do navegador, acabei não colocando na minha resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Na verdade, esse *data-delay-duration* aparece mais de uma vez no site. Não da para usar ID por isso. Além de ser um serviço de terceiro onde eu não consigo manipular isso.

Comment: @FelipeGoulart o ID é apenas exemplo, vou formular um com NodeList, um instante

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento um exemplo de quantas vezes esse atributo aparece no site https://jsfiddle.net/ujhpawoe/1/

Comment: @FelipeGoulart veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Entendi o seu código. O engraçado é que ele não executa o Tampermonkey

Comment: @FelipeGoulart qual erro aparece no console?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não aparece nenhuma erro referente ao atributo. O estranho é que o Tampermonkey está ativado. O *data-delay-replace* continua igual. O código está assim https://jsfiddle.net/a0k32fmj/ O link seria esse https://lp.luzdaserra.com.br/Iniciados-mensal

Comment: @FelipeGoulart veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento infelizmente não funcionou. Mas, deve ser algum problema no Tampermonkey.

Answer (score 0):

Se for com **Vanilla** dá para fazer assim:

```js
var teste = document.getElementById('teste');
teste.dataset.delayDuration = 100;

console.log(teste.dataset.delayDuration);
```

```html
<span id="teste" data-delay-duration="800"></span>
```

Comment: Algo importante a ser comentado: ao fazer `delayduration = 100` você criou outro atributo. O JavaScript diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas e, no `dataset`, o atributo `data-delay-duration` será `dataset.delayDuration`, com o d em *Duration* maiúsculo.

Comment: Verdade Anderson, foi eu que escrevi errado mesmo.

Answer (score -3):

Crie este script no tampermonkey e troque #teste pelo id que você for usar e o respectivo valor na linha `$('#teste').attr("data-delay-duration","400");`.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166478/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-custom-attribute
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

var $ = window.jQuery;

(function() {
    'use strict';
    console.log($('#teste').attr("data-delay-duration"));
    $('#teste').attr("data-delay-duration","400");
    console.log($('#teste').attr("data-delay-duration"));
    // Your code here...
})();
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar uma explicação do que o seu código está fazendo? Sim, fui eu que negativei. Estou dando o feedback, para você não ficar sem saber o que houve.

Comment: Bom... Usando o tampermonkey e jQuery, a resposta é basicamente a linha `$('#teste').attr("data-delay-duration","400");`, que seta o atributo `data-delay-duration` com o valor `400`. O resto é para poder rodar o exemplo.

Comment: Você precisa adicionar isso à resposta. A ideia do site é que a pergunta e a resposta ajudem, não só quem está com o problema atual, mas outros usuários que vierem aqui no futuro. Sugiro que clique em "editar" e adicione os detalhes à sua resposta. **me comprometo** em remover meu negativo, caso algo melhore na sua resposta.

Comment: Bom... eu editei... mas não concordo com os downvotes, qualquer programador entende o que rolava no post original ;). Segue o baile.

Comment: Errado, jovem. Não é qualquer programador [em qualquer nível] que entendo o código só de olhar. Sempre é bom ter uma explicação. Pessoas que estão aprendendo a programar também acessam o site.

Comment: Como prometi, meu downvote foi removido.

Comment: Agora observe a resposta com 0 votes.... Grande diferença, uma com e outra sem jQuery.... Fui o alvo. hahaha

Comment: Particularmente, eu achei que usar `dataset` foi melhor que usar `attr`, visto que o 'jQuery` também possui um recurso melhor que usar `attr`, que é a função `data`.  Eu comentei o meu voto, e acho isso o mais correto pra saber onde errou e melhorar. É uma pena que outros usuários não façam (o medo de retaliação conta, pois já aconteceu muitas vezes).

Comment: **Cross-browser consistency**: The values of some attributes are reported inconsistently across browsers, and even across versions of a single browser. The `.attr()` method reduces such inconsistencies.

Mas não vou entrar nessa discussão. Você tá certo.

Comment: Caro thxmxx o que tampermonkey (add-on) tem haver com a pergunta? Sua resposta inicial mesmo que sem explicações estava bem melhor que a atual https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/322354/1 -- recomendo que volte a primeira e apenas explique o código da outra.